# gdb и valgrind генерируют сообщения об ошибках при включении русской локали

Tags: c, gdb, valgrind

Здравствуйте!

Долгое время не обращал внимания на сообщения в valgrind об ошибках, связанных с локализацией. Главное, чтобы не было утечек. Но вот решил разобраться. Если ставить `С`-локаль, то все нормально. Но как только указываю любую другую, валгринд ругается. gdb ругается тоже. Упростил пример до нескольких строчек.

Компиляторы GCC 4.7, clang (3.3), система ALTLinux.

Вот что пишет gdb:

> Missing separate debuginfo for /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
>   Try to install the hash file /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/4b/17cdb72cc20e7c8b2eb2056ab9eeae5eacb0d3.debug
>   Missing separate debuginfo for /lib64/libc.so.6
>   Try to install the hash file /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/78/2b2756c3af2791386a8c4f3414b4dad6572dde.debug
>   Вот что пишет valgrind (фрагмент):
>   ==3695== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
>   ==3695==    at 0x4EB7B38: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.17.so)
>   ==3695==    by 0x4E5DF5D: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.17.so)
>   ==3695==    by 0x4E5E3C9: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.17.so)
>   ==3695==    by 0x4E56D21: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.17.so)
>   ==3695==    by 0x4EDD807: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.17.so)
>   ==3695==    by 0x4EDD948: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.17.so)
>   ==3695==    by 0x4ED3438: wcsrtombs (in /lib64/libc-2.17.so)
>   ==3695==    by 0x4E7E59B: vfprintf (in /lib64/libc-2.17.so)
>   ==3695==    by 0x4E83FA8: printf (in /lib64/libc-2.17.so)
>   ==3695==    by 0x4005C9: main (test.c:11)
>   ==3695== 
>   ==3695== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
>   ==3695==    at 0x4EB6762: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.17.so)
>   ==3695==    by 0x4E5DF5D: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.17.so)
>   ==3695==    by 0x4E5E429: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.17.so)
>   ==3695==    by 0x4E56D21: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.17.so)
>   ==3695==    by 0x4EDD807: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.17.so)
>   ==3695==    by 0x4EDD969: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.17.so)
>   ==3695==    by 0x4ED3438: wcsrtombs (in /lib64/libc-2.17.so)
>   ==3695==    by 0x4E7E59B: vfprintf (in /lib64/libc-2.17.so)
>   ==3695==    by 0x4E83FA8: printf (in /lib64/libc-2.17.so)
>   ==3695==    by 0x4005C9: main (test.c:11)
>   ==3695== 
>   ==3695== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
>   ==3695==    at 0x4EB7B34: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.17.so)
>   ==3695==    by 0x4E5DF5D: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.17.so)
>   ==3695==    by 0x4E5E429: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.17.so)
>   ==3695==    by 0x4E56D21: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.17.so)
>   ==3695==    by 0x4EDD807: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.17.so)
>   ==3695==    by 0x4EDD969: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.17.so)
>   ==3695==    by 0x4ED3438: wcsrtombs (in /lib64/libc-2.17.so)
>   ==3695==    by 0x4E7E59B: vfprintf (in /lib64/libc-2.17.so)
>   ==3695==    by 0x4E83FA8: printf (in /lib64/libc-2.17.so)
>   ==3695==    by 0x4005C9: main (test.c:11)
>   ==3695== 
>   ==3695== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
>   ==3695==    at 0x4EB7B38: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.17.so)
>   ==3695==    by 0x4E5DF5D: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.17.so)
>   ==3695==    by 0x4E5E429: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.17.so)
>   ==3695==    by 0x4E56D21: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.17.so)
>   ==3695==    by 0x4EDD807: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.17.so)
>   ==3695==    by 0x4EDD969: ??? (in /lib64/libc-2.17.so)
>   ==3695==    by 0x4ED3438: wcsrtombs (in /lib64/libc-2.17.so)
>   ==3695==    by 0x4E7E59B: vfprintf (in /lib64/libc-2.17.so)
>   ==3695==    by 0x4E83FA8: printf (in /lib64/libc-2.17.so)
>   ==3695==    by 0x4005C9: main (test.c:11)
>   ==3695== 
>   Hello!
>   ==3695== 
>   ==3695== HEAP SUMMARY:
>   ==3695==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>   ==3695==   total heap usage: 197 allocs, 197 frees, 10,382 bytes allocated
>   ==3695== 
>   ==3695== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
>   ==3695== 
>   ==3695== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
>   ==3695== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
>   ==3695== ERROR SUMMARY: 630 errors from 42 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)

Код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <wctype.h>

int main()
{
    //setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL);
    //setlocale(LC_ALL, "POSIX"); // ошибки исчезают, но русский текст не печатает
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    wchar_t a[] = L"Hello";
    printf("%S!\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Компиляция: `gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -std=с11 test.c -o test`.

В каком направлении действовать дальше:

1. Писать обертки для системных функций?
2. Установить что-то для отладки?
3. Перейти на более новую версию компилятора и другую ОС?
4. Забить на все и спокойно писать код дальше?
5. Ещё что-то?

Честно говоря, с альтлинукса переходить на другую ОС не хочется, ровно как и отказываться от gcc (хотя 4.7 не полностью поддерживает стандарт с11).

Comment: #define _GNU_SOURCE   setlocale(LC_ALL, "");  wchar_t a[] = L"Привет"; wprintf(L"%S!\n", a);

Comment: Пробую установить xubuntu. Там компилятор поновее.

Comment: Забейте на `w_char` (используйте `utf-8`)

Comment: utf-8 я знаю, нужна регулярность для обработки строк - один чимвол - четкое количество байт. wchar_t люди придумали не случайно.

Comment: Только учтите, при неправильном символе во входной последовательности wchar поток (`FILE *` тоже) не восстанавливается. Поэтому если нужна надежность (например, при работе по сети (сокеты)), то все равно придется обмениваться в побайтном режиме и переводить в wchar руками (например, используя mbtowc/ mbstowcs или iconv)

Comment: Спасибо за ценный совет. Да, для сокетов надо. Что же до функций перекодировки - то у меня целая библиотека адаптеров. А для внутреннего представления - wchar_t незаменим.

Comment: Если не связываться с нестандартными `regwcomp`/`regwexec` и не думать о памяти.

Comment: Память отшлифована. Утечек нет. Единственный минус - расход памяти для wchar_t на порядки больше чем для utf-8. Но чтобы не тратить время на кучу перекодировок для разных языков (держать все однобайтной кодировке) проще использовать wcs* функции.

Answer (score 0):

Установил xubuntu. На gcc 6.3 все работает отлично, плюс все возможности с11!